# Can't Use Next/Link with NextJs 13 app directory

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, hyperlink, components

when i enable nextjs 13 appDir feature and add a Link i get and error of
" Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call') "
in the console i also see another error
" Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering. "
here is my code

> 

```
import Link from 'next/link';

function Header() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link href="/">Home</Link>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

```
inside the appDir i have 
layout.tsx
page.tsx
head.tsx
Header.tsx
```

i havnt yet changed anything in any of them expect that i added the Header component in the layout.tsx

> 

```
import Header from './Header';
import '../styles/globals.css';
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html>
      <head />
      <body>
        <Header />
       {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

ONLY WHEN I AM ADDING 'LINK'
if im not using the appdir and using good old ./pages it's fine..
what's wrong here ? because i saw many tutorials and im just copying and pasting i also get the same error when adding Link

Answer (score 0):

this is how i use navigation link with tailwind. I have this component placed in app/components/navigation/NavigationLink.tsx

```
import Link, { LinkProps } from "next/link"

export type NavigationLinkProps = {
  label: string
  icon?: React.ReactNode
  href: string
} & LinkProps

function NavigationLink(props: NavigationLinkProps) {
  return (
  <Link 
    {...props}
    href={props.href}
    className='flex w-full h-11 items-center rounded bg-white px-2 gap-2'
  >
    {props.icon}
    <div className='flex-1'>
      { props.label }
    </div>
  </Link>
  )
}

export default NavigationLink
```

It works just fine with

```
href: '/'
```

I hope this helps.